# URL router for production

Tags: c++, url-routing

So I've written a URL router which also allows for wildcards (path parameters).

A URL like `/users/{uuid}` can be added and then, when a user sends a request to the server with the following target `/users/955b2a88-ae80-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004`, the uuid will then equal `955b2a88-ae80-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004`.

Example:

```
PathMatcher<int> matcher(-1);
matcher.add_path("/users/{uuid}", 1);

Parameters parameters;
assert(matcher.match("/users/9c4ceec8-f929-434e-8ff1-837dd54b7b56", parameters) == 1);
assert(parameters.find("uuid", "") == "9c4ceec8-f929-434e-8ff1-837dd54b7b56");
```

I have learned C++ through Stack Overflow, therefore I don't really have an idea how production ready code should look like.

I'd like to know what should be written differently and would could be improved.

If you'd like to run the code, it is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/nilsegger/url-router) with an example `main.cpp`.

```
typedef std::string string_t;

class Parameters {
    std::vector<std::pair<string_t, string_t>> parameters_;

public:

    void add(string_t& name, string_t& value) {
        parameters_.emplace_back(name, value);
    }

    string_t find(string_t name, string_t default_="") {
        for(auto & parameter : parameters_) {
            if(parameter.first == name) return parameter.second;
        }
        return default_;
    }

    void clear() {
        parameters_.clear();
    }
};

template<typename Result>
class PathMatcher {

    struct Path {
        char character;
        std::vector<Path *> children;
        std::optional<Result> result;

        Path(char character, std::optional<Result> result) : character(character), result(result) {}

        ~Path() {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                delete children[i];
            }
        }
    };

    Path *
    find_child(char character, std::vector<Path *> &parent, bool findWildcard = false, Path **wildcard = nullptr) {
        Path *child = nullptr;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < parent.size(); i++) {
            if (parent[i]->character == character) {
                child = parent[i];
                // If wildcards are not wanted, there is no need to continue
                if (!findWildcard) break;
            } else if (findWildcard && parent[i]->character == wildcard_open_) {
                (*wildcard) = parent[i];
                // If child has already been found, there is no need to continue
                if (child != nullptr) break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }

    Path *create_path(std::vector<Path *> &parent, char character, std::optional<Result> value) {
        Path *route = new Path(character, value);
        parent.push_back(route);
        return route;
    }

    void insert_path(string_t &path, Result &result, Path *step = nullptr, int path_pos = 0) {
        /*
         * Recursively creates path. A path contains a vector with child paths.
         * These linked paths create a chain which can be walked down.
         * If we input /users/a and /users/b the following chain would be created.
         * / -> u -> s -> e -> r -> s -> / -> a
         *                                 -> b
         *
         * Now if you want to match against an input, this chain can be walked down until a path no longer contains the matching character.
         * If the input would equal /users/c, the chain would be walked until the last '/' and then failing because it only contains the children a & b, not c.
         *
         * The last two paths (a & b) will contains a value. This value states that the path has reached its end.
         */
        assert(path.size() > 1);
        if (path_pos == path.size() - 1) {
            // last insertion accompanied by ending value
            Path *child = find_child(path[path_pos], step->children);

            if (child != nullptr) {
                assert(!child->result); // Cant already have a value
                child->result = result;
            } else {
                create_path(step->children, path[path_pos], result);
            }
        } else {

            Path *child;
            if (path_pos == 0) {
                child = find_child(path[path_pos], paths_);
            } else {
                child = find_child(path[path_pos], step->children);
            }

            if (child == nullptr && path_pos == 0) {
                child = create_path(paths_, path[path_pos], std::nullopt);
            } else if (child == nullptr) {
                child = create_path(step->children, path[path_pos], std::nullopt);
            }

            return insert_path(path, result, child, path_pos + 1);
        }
    }

    void get_wildcard_name(Path **wildcard, string_t &wildcard_name) {
        /*
         * /users/{uuid} and users/{uuid}/friends is allowed
         * /users/{uuid} and users/{id}/friends is not allowed, because wildcards at the same positions must match
         *
         * This method walks down the chain until the wildcard_close_ character has been found. Everything between start and end is appended to the value.
         */
        assert((*wildcard)->children.size() == 1);
        if ((*wildcard)->children[0]->character != wildcard_close_) {
            wildcard_name.append(1, (*wildcard)->children[0]->character);
            *wildcard = (*wildcard)->children[0];
            get_wildcard_name(wildcard, wildcard_name);
        } else {
            *wildcard = (*wildcard)->children[0];
        }
    }

    string_t get_wildcard_value(string_t &path, size_t &pos) {
        // Walks down the input until the trailing_wildcard_ is found or the end is reached, everything between equals the wildcard value
        int begin = pos;
        for (; pos < path.size() - 1; pos++) {
            if (path[pos + 1] == trailing_wildcard_) {
                return path.substr(begin, pos - begin + 1);
            }
        }
        return path.substr(begin);
    }

    std::vector<Path *> paths_;
    Result default_;
    char wildcard_open_;
    char wildcard_close_;
    char trailing_wildcard_;

public:

    PathMatcher(Result default_, char wildcard_open='{', char wildcard_close='}', char trailing_wildcard='/')
        : default_(default_), wildcard_open_(wildcard_open), wildcard_close_(wildcard_close), trailing_wildcard_(
                                                                                                            trailing_wildcard) {}


    virtual ~PathMatcher() {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < paths_.size(); i++) {
            delete paths_[i];
        }
    }

    void add_path(string_t path, Result value) {
        insert_path(path, value);
    }

    Result match(string_t path, Parameters &variables) {
        /*
         * Starts at paths_ and continues trying to find children matching the next characters in input path.
         * If there is no child which matches the next character, but there was a wildcard_open_ as a child,
         * the code jumps back to it and sets a Parameters value for the wildcard with its value and then continues normally.
         */
        Path *step = find_child(path[0], paths_);
        if (step == nullptr) return default_;

        Path *lastWildcard = nullptr;
        size_t lastWildcardPos;
        size_t i = 1;
        for (; i < path.size() - 1 && step != nullptr; i++) {

            Path *nextWildcard = nullptr;
            step = find_child(path[i], step->children, true, &nextWildcard);

            if (nextWildcard != nullptr && nextWildcard != lastWildcard) {
                lastWildcardPos = i;
                lastWildcard = nextWildcard;
            }
            if (path[i] == trailing_wildcard_) {
                lastWildcard = nullptr;
            }

            if (step == nullptr && lastWildcard != nullptr) {
                i = lastWildcardPos;

                string_t wildcard_name;
                get_wildcard_name(&lastWildcard, wildcard_name);
                string_t wildcard_value = get_wildcard_value(path, i);
                variables.add(wildcard_name, wildcard_value);

                if (i == path.size() - 1) {
                    // Wildcard value reaches end
                    if (!lastWildcard->result) return default_;
                    return lastWildcard->result.value();
                } else {
                    step = lastWildcard;
                }
            }
        }

        if (step == nullptr) return default_;

        Path *wildcard = nullptr;
        Path *result = find_child(path[path.size() - 1], step->children, true, &wildcard);

        if(result != nullptr && result->result) return result->result.value();
        else if(wildcard != nullptr) {
            // find wildcard ending and check if it contains a value
            string_t wildcardName;
            get_wildcard_name(&wildcard, wildcardName);

            if(!wildcard->result) return default_;

            string_t value = path.substr(path.size() - 1);
            variables.add(wildcardName, value);
            return wildcard->result.value();
        }

        return default_;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `std::basic_regex`?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with regex and I thought it would end up being faster like this. @Edward

Comment: Regular expressions are usually very fast. Another benefit is that you can make your patterns much more precise: in your example, the UUID pattern matches anything that comes after `/user/`, even if what follows doesn't look like a UUID at all. With regular expressions, you can write [a pattern that only accepts valid UUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your program.

### Separate interface from implementation

It makes the code somewhat longer for a code review, but it's often very useful to separate the interface from the implementation.  In C++, this is usually done by putting the interface into separate `.h` files and the corresponding implementation into `.cpp` files.  It helps users (or reviewers) of the code see and understand the interface and hides implementation details.  The other important reason is that you might have multiple source files including the `.h` file but only one instance of the corresponding `.cpp` file.  In other words, split your existing `.h` file into a `.h` file and a `.cpp` file.  The templated class, by contrast, can stay in a `.h` file.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The code uses `std::pair` but doesn't `#include <utility>`.  Also, carefully consider which `#include`s are part of the interface (and belong in the `.h` file) and which are part of the implementation per the above advice.

### Reconsider the interface

It doesn't seem very useful to me to have the `PathMatcher` return an `int`.  What would be more useful, I think, would be for it to return a `Parameters` object.  That would also probably eliminate the need for `Parameters::clear()`.

### Use standard libraries more effectively

The `Parameters` object currently iterates through its parameters to find a match.  I would suggest that instead of this existing line:

```
std::vector<std::pair<string_t, string_t>> parameters_;
```

a more appropriate data structure would be this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> parameters_;
```

That would make `find` very simple:

```
std::string Parameters::find(std::string key, std::string notfound) const {
    auto result = parameters_.find(key);
    return result == parameters_.end() ? notfound : result->second;
}
```

Here again, the interface is strange.  I don't see much use in passing back a passed string if the key is not found.  I'd expect to have an exception thrown instead.  That renders the function even simpler:

```
std::string Parameters::find(std::string key) const {
    return parameters_.at(key);
}
```

### Use `<regex>` to greatly simplify the code

This code could be much simpler, even without altering the interface, by using `std::regex`.  Here's what the include file would look like:

#### parameter.h

```
#ifndef PARAMETER_H
#define PARAMETER_H
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


class Parameters {
public:
    std::string find(std::string name, std::string notfound = "") const;
    void clear();
    template <class T>
    friend class PathMatcher;
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m;
};

struct Pattern {
    Pattern(std::string path);
    std::regex re;
    std::vector<std::string> names;
};

template <class T>
class PathMatcher {
public:
    PathMatcher(T init) : nomatch{init} {}
    void add_path(std::string pattern, T value) {
        patterns.emplace_back(pattern, value);
    }
    T match(std::string input, Parameters& p) {
        T answer{nomatch};
        for (const auto& patpair : patterns) {
            std::smatch m;
            if (std::regex_match(input, m, patpair.first.re)) {
                answer = patpair.second;
                for (unsigned i{1}; i < m.size(); ++i) {
                    p.m[patpair.first.names[i-1]] = m[i].str();
                }
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
private:
    T nomatch;
    std::vector<std::pair<Pattern, T>> patterns;
};

#endif // PARAMETER_H
```

This is the implementation file:

#### parameter.cpp

```
#include "parameter.h"

std::string Parameters::find(std::string name, std::string notfound) const {
    auto result = m.find(name);
    return result == m.end() ? notfound : result->second;
}

void Parameters::clear() {
    m.clear();
}

Pattern::Pattern(std::string path) {
    static const std::regex vble{R"(\{[^\}]*\})"};
    auto start = std::sregex_iterator{path.begin(), path.end(), vble}; 
    auto finish = std::sregex_iterator{};
    for (auto it{start}; it != finish; ++it) {
        auto str = it->str();
        str.erase(0, 1);  // remove {
        str.pop_back(); // remove }
        names.push_back(str);
    }
    re = std::regex_replace(path, vble, "(.*)");
}
```

When I tested it, it's exactly as fast as the original version (both ran in 5ms on my machine).

Comment: _I don't see much use in passing back a passed string if the key is not found_ I assume that parameters are optional (possibly passed on the command line), so when you ask for the value of one of these having the default value returned (instead of having to handle a not found exception to set that) can simplify the code.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that the original implementation of `Parameters` does not handle duplicate parameters properly. It will return the original (first) value added if an "updated" value is added. Using some form of map will replace the existing value with the new value.

Comment: Passing `std::string` without the `&` looks unusual to me. Did I miss the latest developments?

Comment: @RolandIllig: It depends where you mean.  For `find` it would make sense to pass `const std::string &` but for the `Pattern` constructor, since we need to make a copy anyway, it makes sense.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: if I say "tell me how many oranges you have or say 'bleep' if you have no oranges" I don't see how that simplifies things over "tell me how many oranges you have or throw an exception if you don't know what I'm asking about."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, helps me a lot. There is just one point I dont understand. What do you mean with "Also, carefully consider which #includes are part of the interface (and belong in the .h file) and which are part of the implementation per the above advice." Even after splitting the code, dont all includes belong into the .h file? @Edward

Comment: Only `#include`s that are required to understand the interface go in the`.h` file. So if, for example I had used something from `<cmath>` in `parameter.cpp` that `#include` would go only in the `.cpp` file since it’s an internal detail not relevant to the interface.